# how to get the current page id in wordpress using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

how to get a page id in wordpress using jquery alone.I am planing to change some styles of a page using a custom script for which i need to know page id.

Answer (score 9):

```
function get_current_page_id() {
    var page_body = $('body.page');

    var id = 0;

    if(page_body) {
        var classList = page_body.attr('class').split(/\s+/);

        $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
            if (item.indexOf('page-id') >= 0) {
                var item_arr = item.split('-');
                id =  item_arr[item_arr.length -1];
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return id;
}
```

Add this function to your code.
You can now get the page id by using:

```
var id = get_current_page_id();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `wp_localize_script`.

```
function my_custom_vars() {

global $wp_query;
    $vars = array(
        'postID' => $wp_query->post->ID,
    );

wp_localize_script( 'myvars', 'MyScriptVars', $vars );
}  

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_vars');
```

You can use the vaiables in your scripts this way..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyPostID = MyScriptVars.postID;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the current page id in jQuery alone you can do it in following steps:

- First make hidden input or hidden HTML tag and add the current page id in it by id of the element: `c_pageid` and the value `get_the_ID();`
- In your jQuery file you can get this value by id like `var pageId=$("#c_pageid").val();`

This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-3202")) {   
        // code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by adding global javascript variables via PHP.

To do this first add the following script to your page.php template file:

```
<script>
var pageId = <?php echo isset($posts[0]) ? $posts[0]->ID : 'null'; ?>;
</script>
```

Now in in your javascript code you are able to use this global variable like this.

```
<script>
if(pageId !== undefined && pageId) {
 // do some code based on pageId
}
</script>
```

You can use this same technique to use other WordPress variables in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pageId="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"
```

Use the above line in your script

Answer (score 0):

```
var current_page_id = get_current_page_id();

    function get_current_page_id() {
        var page_body = $('body.page');
        var page_id = '';
        if(page_body) {
            var classList = page_body.attr('class').split(/\s+/);

            $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
                if (item.indexOf('page-id') >= 0) {
                    page_id = item;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        return page_id;
    }
```