# How can I get the ID of current page or post in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, post

I need to get the id of the current post/page. I was using this code:

```
function get_current_page_id() {
    var page_body = $('body.page');

    var id = 0;

    if (page_body) {
        var classList = page_body.attr('class').split(/\s+/);

        $.each(classList, function (index, item) {
            if (item.indexOf('page-id') >= 0) {
                var item_arr = item.split('-');
                id = item_arr[item_arr.length - 1];
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return id;
}
```

From here: [how to get the current page id in wordpress using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395366/how-to-get-the-current-page-id-in-wordpress-using-jquery)

But as I understand, this only works for the type: 'page'. It's giving me some problems, and I would like it to work for the type 'post' too (and maybe custom type posts, though I don't have any of those currently and it's not very important).

I am a bit weak with this, so can anyone kindly transform it to work for posts too? (So it should return the id irrespective of the type).

I am thinking it's a simple fix of removing the '.page' from `$('body.page')` in the beginning - but maybe not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use wp_localize_script see an example [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211831/get-the-current-post-id-as-a-variable-in-javascript/211837)

Answer (score 1):

This script is grabbing the body element class name segment that begins with `page-id`. Simply switch that with `post-id`.

```
if (item.indexOf('post-id') >= 0) {
```

I verified that such a class value exists on [the official WordPress blog](https://wordpress.org/news/2019/09/people-of-wordpress-abdullah-ramzan/). To look for and act on both cases, try this:

```
$.each(classList, function (index, item) {
    // check for page ID *or* post ID
    if (item.indexOf('page-id') >= 0 || item.indexOf('post-id') >= 0) {
        var item_arr = item.split('-');
        id = item_arr[item_arr.length - 1];
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: In that way, wouldn't it be working for posts only? I wouldn't have solved the problem because I need to work for posts and pages at the same time (unless post-id is also there in pages).

Comment: Answer updated. You'll have to experiment a bit for your use-case. I don't have enough information to be sure this is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can take Current Page ID in jquery as below:

Put this code in `functions.php` file

```
function functionname() {

$pageid = get_the_ID();

    echo '<input type="hidden" id="get_page_id" value="'.$pageid.'">';  


}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'functionname' );
```

now in jquery script file put this

`var pageid = $(#get_page_id).val();
console.log(pageid )`

you will get page id

Comment: OP wants to know the ID of the current *post/page*, not the user ID.

Comment: Okay, I have changed my code by using that you can get page id in script

Comment: @cabrerahector please try out above code and let me know it will work..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  `the_ID()` function if you just want the number of the page or post.

More on that here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_id/

If that doesn't work, let us know what specific use you wish the ID for. There are different ways of retrieving that.

Comment: Thank you. As I said, I am bit weak with this stuff, so for me, this looks like a predefined PHP function, whereas I need to use it in jQuery. Maybe it doesn't matter and I can use it anyway? I am a bit confused but might try this, so thank you again